# Custom class with recursion in methods, global name not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a method for which is necessary to use recursion, but every time, I get the `global name not defined` error
My class look like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def _init_(self, name=None, content=None):
        self.name = name
        self.content = content
```

It's a node class, name it's just a text string and content a list of it's children (they are nodes too), is initialized as `None` but the construction function that builds the tree give them a blank list if they have no children. The class works fine and so does the function but if I try to add recurtion to methods they just don't work, even if they work just fine as a standalone function, i.e.:

```
def get_nodes(self):
    c = [] 
    c.append(self.name)
    if self.content != []:
        for a in self.content:
            c.extend(get_nodes(a))
    return c
```

I know this is possible, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do `a.get_nodes()`.

Also the initialization method is called `__init__`, not `_init_` (two underscores on both ends).

Edit: If you won't show your code, we can't tell you what's wrong with your code.  This code works for me:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, content=None):
        self.name = name
        self.content = content
    def get_nodes(self):
        c = [] 
        c.append(self.name)
        if self.content != []:
            for a in self.content:
                c.extend(a.get_nodes())
        return c

>>> n = MyClass('me', [])
>>> m = MyClass('other', [n])
>>> m.get_nodes()
['other', 'me']
```

If your code doesn't work then you have to explain how your code is different from that.

Comment: Thank you very much, one of the two methods worked just fine after doing this(writing it as an instance method, I belive is called), the other one, and is the funtion in the example, did not worked. I keep getting the same error, the init was just a typo, I've got it right in the class.

Comment: @Janbure: I don't quite get what you mean.  Are you saying that `get_nodes` is a method (i.e., is inside a class definition) or not?  How are you calling it?  Can you post a complete runnable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yes it is inside a class like the one I've posted in the op, I can't post the full code cause it is for an assignment and I'm afraid to be copied, also I don't want to make you people to do my homework, but it looks just like the one I've posted. My biggest concern is why it doesn't work as a method called like this, node.get_nodes(), but it does work as a pure function?

Comment: @Janbure: If you don't show your code, no one can tell you what's wrong with it.  I edited my answer with working code.  Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Yes it did helped me a lot, the method I posted is used by a count method that I forgot to modify, now everything is running smooth, thank you very much.

Comment: Another think, I've been struggling for days to get a method to find the height of my tree, that is just a node with the children node as content. I can't find a way to traverse the tree right, since it's not binary. How I should approach that?

Comment: @Janbure: You should post that as a separate question, along with your code.